# How to click the submenu using mouseMove in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want click the submenu(coordinates2) in my following code.I have tried such methods using WebElement.But it doesn't work.And menu will be in mouse over funtion.Pls help me out of this issue.

```
    Point coordinates = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[1]")).getLocation();
    Point coordinates1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div[1]")).getLocation();
    Point coordinates2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[5]/div[1]")).getLocation();
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX()+3,coordinates.getY()+150);
    robot.mouseMove(coordinates1.getX()+50,coordinates1.getY()+240);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    robot.mouseMove(coordinates2.getX()+200,coordinates2.getY()+240);
```

The below is the Html code.

```
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="" onload="dyninit();init();" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<div id="transboxdiv" class="transbox">
<iframe id="disablePageframe" scrolling="no" style="z-index: 150;position:absolute;display:none;background-color:#ffffcc;border: 0 solid black; allowtranaparency:true"/>
<div id="disablePage" class="options" border="0" style="z-index:150; font-family:'Microsoft Sans Serif';font-size:13px;display:none;position:absolute;text-align:center;"/>

<div style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 617px; height: 20px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 8pt; z-index: 101; top: 64px; left: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; visibility: inherit; overflow: hidden; cursor: default; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(25, 63, 148); text-align: left; width: 65px; height: 16px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 2px; left: 1px; top: 1px;">Masters</div>
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 142px; height: 236px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 8pt; z-index: 102; top: 84px; left: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; visibility: inherit; overflow: hidden; cursor: default; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(25, 63, 148); text-align: left; width: 140px; height: 16px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 2px; left: 1px; top: 1px;">Material Group</div>
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 162px; height: 56px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 8pt; z-index: 103; top: 85.8px; left: 127px;">
<div style="position: absolute; visibility: inherit; overflow: hidden; cursor: default; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(25, 63, 148); text-align: left; width: 160px; height: 16px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 2px; left: 1px; top: 1px;">Material Group-Add</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide html code?

Answer (score 0):

Clicking a sub-menu is easy.  As soon as you click the menu and the content appears, the page DOM might change and load the menu contents.   At that point you should be able to see the elements in the page source and iterate through them as a list using the Selenium getElements(By) method.

Comment: I show an example here, for Etsy.com search page:  https://github.com/djangofan/selenium-gradle-example/blob/master/etsy/src/main/java/qa/webdriver/util/EtsySearchPage.java

Comment: I tried even using Webelement too.But no change.Any suggestions?

Comment: Using the FirePath plugin for Firefox Firebug might help you discover the locators of your menu and also test css and xpath selectors without having to write code.